# wxpython not showing the entire grid

Tags: grid, wxpython

I have a wxpython csv reader.  I am displaying results on a grid. The grid will take about half of my screen. I would like to display 100 rows at a time.  I assign there to be 100 rows but I can not scroll to the bottom 50.  I have proved that the rows are there by writing to the rows that I can not see then copying the whole column and pasting in excel.  What I am expecting to see is a scroll bar that allows me to scroll to the bottom 50.  I allowed editing of size of column.  When I increase the height of the column, the scroll bar appears,but still only allows me to view the top 50 columns.  (if user makes column height a inch bigger than normal, my scroll adds an inch)  My best guess is there is something wrong with the way I am initiating/getting the best size of the combinations of sizers,panels,and the grid.  I have cut out the code that not needed but the layout panel and box are my overall/main panel and box.

```
import wx.grid as grd
import wx
self.layoutPanel = wx.Panel(self)
self.layoutBox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
self.previewPanel = wx.Panel(self.layoutPanel)
self.previewBox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
self.resultGrid = grd.Grid.__init__(self, self.previewPanel,0)
self.resultGrid.CreateGrid(105,20)
self.previewBox.Add(self.resultGrid,0, wx.GROW)
self.resultGrid.SetSize(self.resultGrid.GetBestSize())
self.previewPanel.SetSizer(self.previewBox)
self.layoutBox.Add(self.previewPanel,0, wx.ALL)
self.layoutPanel.SetSizerAndFit(self.layoutBox)    
self.layoutPanel.Layout()
```

Comment: I don't see a call to CreateGrid where you actually tell the grid the number of columns and rows there should be. If you don't do that, then you should use the widget in virtual mode.

Comment: Yes I forgot to add the code to the example but I did have that in my original code.  Some of these lines I had to change to understand what I am trying to accomplish, since I have this code broken out into different places.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was nested somewhere in having 2 panels in side one another. This is normally "ok" to do but it is a little more complicated with the grid. I got rid of the previewPanel and previewBox completely and that solved the problem.  However another problem was the FIT.  The fit makes the panel as small as possible which is not what I wanted to happen.  In code not shown I had re-sizes occurring and when I did this I had setSizeAndFit which took the scroll away.  I changed it to setSize and the scroll bar stayed.